# Fetch recursive tree with only certain elements "expanded"

Tags: oracle, recursion

We have a table with a self-referencing tree structure (`id`, `parent_id`). Let's assume the following tree structure:

```
+ 1
  + 2
  + 3
  + 4
    + 5
    + 6
    + 7
  + 8
+ 9
  + 10
  + 11
```

I'd like to fetch this data for displaying it in a tree. But only certain records expanded. I'm currently using the following query:

```
SELECT ID, NAME "PATH"
  FROM GROUPS
  WHERE PRIOR ID IN(1, 4)
  CONNECT BY PARENT_ID = PRIOR ID
  START WITH PARENT_ID IS NULL;
```

This works very well and returns the following records:

```
+ 1
  + 2
  + 3
  + 4
    + 5
    + 6
    + 7
  + 8
+ 9
```

The problem is that this query returns every record of which the direct parent is expanded, but not the whole parent chain. So if we're just expanding id `4`, records `5, 6, 7` still shouldn't be returned as `1` is not expanded.

What I have been trying so far is to fetch a custom column which indicates whether the element is expanded, which computes out of whether it is explicitly expanded AND the parent is expanded as well.

```
SELECT ...
CASE WHEN (ID IN (4) AND PRIOR EXPANDED = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 end "EXPANDED"
...
WHERE "EXPANDED" = 1
```

This does not work as I can use the `EXPANDED` alias neither in the WHERE statement nor the `PRIOR EXPANDED` statement.

Is there a simple way of achieving this using a simple query?

Comment: Are you trying to expand the hierarchy to show only a ids with their siblings, its ancestors and the siblings of those ancestors? (and conversely not showing descendants, and descendants of siblings/ancestors siblings). Will there only be a single element (i.e. in your example, 4) or can you have expanded elements on multiple unrelated branches?

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I'm aiming for. There can be multiple expanded, unrelated branches. Think of it as a normal tree where the user can expand / collapse elements at will. Expanding happens solely through a list of node IDs that should be expanded. But it is well possible that the user collapses an item which contains expanded children. My current approach still shows these children, but without their parent (so they're 'hanging' in the nowhere). Thanks for your help!

Comment: updated my answer to address your need for the entire parent-chain to be expanded. Sorry - missed that first time around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE hierarchy ( id, parent_id ) AS
  SELECT 1, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 8 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query - `IN` clause has all parents explanded**:

```
SELECT LPAD( '+ ', LEVEL*2, ' ' ) || id
FROM   hierarchy
START WITH parent_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
AND        parent_id IN ( 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9 );
```

**Output**:

```
+ 1
  + 2
    + 3
  +4
    + 5
      + 6
+ 7
  + 8
    + 9
      + 10
    + 11
```

**Query - `IN` clause has all parents expanded except 4 and 8**:

```
SELECT LPAD( '+ ', LEVEL*2, ' ' ) || id
FROM   hierarchy
START WITH parent_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
AND        parent_id IN ( 1, 2, 5, 7, 9 );
```

**Output**:

```
+ 1
  + 2
    + 3
  +4
+ 7
  + 8
```

**Update - Showing leaf nodes**:

```
SELECT LPAD( '+ ', LEVEL*2, ' ' ) || id AS value,
       isleaf
FROM   (
  -- Find the leaves first (as if all parents are expanded)
  SELECT h.*,
         CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF AS isLeaf
  FROM   hierarchy h
  START WITH parent_id IS NULL
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
)
START WITH parent_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
AND        parent_id IN ( 1, 2, 4, 7, 9 );
```

**Output**:

```
VALUE                ISLEAF
---------------- ----------
+ 1                       0 
  + 2                     0 
    + 3                   1 
  + 4                     0 
    + 5                   0 
+ 7                       0 
  + 8                     0
```

`1` Indicates that the node has no children and `0` indicates that the node has children (even though they might not be expanded).

Comment: How would you extend this query to check if a node is a leaf?

Comment: Do you count leaves as having no children or having no expanded children? The latter is much easier as you just add `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF` to the selected columns.

Comment: As having no children at all. CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF doesn't work here as it only considers the tree defined by the CONNECT BY condition.

Comment: @SanoJ See my update - you need an inner query which finds the leaves as if all the nodes are expanded and then an outer query which applies the filters.

Answer (score 0):

OK, just saw your note about requiring the entire parent chain to be expanded. The following does this by using sys_connect_by_path to build that chain, then checking that it is all 1's (have to lop off the last node which is at the current level):

With 1 and 4 expanded you get:

```
  WITH hier as (
  SELECT 1 id, NULL parent_id, 1 expanded FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 2, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 4, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 4, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 4, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 9, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 9, 0 FROM DUAL )
SELECT LPAD( '+ ', lvl*2, ' ' ) || id
FROM (
      SELECT ID
           , parent_id 
           , level as lvl
           , sys_connect_by_path(expanded,'-')  as path_expanded 
        FROM hier
     CONNECT BY PARENT_ID = PRIOR ID
       START WITH PARENT_ID IS NULL
     )
WHERE --every node in the path from the parent is expanded.
     instr(substr(path_expanded,1,length(path_expanded)-2),'0') = 0
OR   parent_id is null     ; 


LPAD('+',LVL*2,'')||ID 
+ 1                    
  + 2                  
  + 4                  
    + 5                
    + 6                
    + 7                
  + 8                  
  + 9
```

Change to un-expand at node 1 and you get:

```
WITH hier as (
  SELECT 1 id, NULL parent_id, 0 expanded FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 2, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 4, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 4, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 4, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 9, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 9, 0 FROM DUAL )
SELECT LPAD( '+ ', lvl*2, ' ' ) || id
FROM (
      SELECT ID
           , parent_id 
           , level as lvl
           , sys_connect_by_path(expanded,'-')  as path_expanded 
        FROM hier
     CONNECT BY PARENT_ID = PRIOR ID
       START WITH PARENT_ID IS NULL
     )
WHERE --every node in the path from the parent is expanded.
     instr(substr(path_expanded,1,length(path_expanded)-2),'0') = 0
OR   parent_id is null ;



    LPAD('+',LVL*2,'')||ID 
    + 1
```